# How long does it take to get a code-signing certificate from Comodo?

Tags: certificate

I'm looking at buying a code-signing certificate from Comodo (they seem to be the cheapest).

Can someone who has done this tell me how long it takes to issue the certificate once you submit your business documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took us about 1 business day, once we faxed all the necessary docs

Answer (score 1):

Took me about 3 business days in the end

Answer (score 0):

It took us 8 business days (10 total days) to receive ours, but Comodo had a hard time verifying our company.  I recommend submitting your DUNS # as well as your yellowbook.com listing to them to aid in speeding up the request.  We did not do so originally, and they were trying to verify us through a list of 3rd party websites I'd never even heard of before that our information was not on, or was incorrect on.